# Analytic Sliding Windows function in Python Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, analytics, window-functions

Have table:

```
list_1= [['2016-01-01',1,'King', 1000],    
        ['2016-01-02',1,'King', -200],    
        ['2016-01-03',1,'King', 100],    
        ['2016-01-04',1,'King',-400],    
        ['2016-01-05',1,'King', 200],    
        ['2016-01-06',1,'King',  -200],    
        ['2016-01-01',2,'Smith',  1000],    
        ['2016-01-02',2,'Smith',  -300],    
        ['2016-01-03',2,'Smith',  -600],    
        ['2016-01-04',2,'Smith',  100],    
        ['2016-01-05',2,'Smith',  -100]]
labels=['a_date','c_id','c_name','c_action']
df=pd.DataFrame(list_1,columns=labels)
df
```

OUT:

```
    a_date       c_id   c_name  c_action
0   2016-01-01     1    King    1000
1   2016-01-02     1    King    -200
2   2016-01-03     1    King    100
3   2016-01-04     1    King    -400
4   2016-01-05     1    King    200
5   2016-01-06     1    King    -200
6   2016-01-01     2    Smith   1000
7   2016-01-02     2    Smith   -300
8   2016-01-03     2    Smith   -600
9   2016-01-04     2    Smith   100
10  2016-01-05     2    Smith   -100
```

Need to get table:

```
a_date      c_id    c_name  c_amount    Balance
2016-01-01     1    King    1000        1000
2016-01-02     1    King    -200        800
2016-01-03     1    King    100         900
2016-01-04     1    King    -400        500
2016-01-05     1    King    200         700
2016-01-06     1    King    -200        500
2016-01-01     2    Smith   1000        1000
2016-01-02     2    Smith   -300        700
2016-01-03     2    Smith   -600        100
2016-01-04     2    Smith   100         200
2016-01-05     2    Smith   -100        100
```

So i need make "Balance" column with cumulative amount after each action for each customer.
This equivalent for SQL query :

```
SELECT *,
        SUM(c_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY c_id ORDER BY a_date) AS 'Balance'
FROM account_actions
```

For both customers the solution is not difficult, can divide table by c_id, summarize and consolidate back.But it should be a dynamic solution for 10000 customers ...

Comment: What database do you use ?

Comment: This specific sample data is for illustrating a question.

Comment: Database can be : MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer, SQLite, PostgreSQL...

Comment: SQLServer Database

Comment: I think you are looking for cumsum, df['balance'] = df.groupby('c_id')['c_action'].cumsum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vaishali commented, this is `groupby` and `cumsum`. You may want to do `sort_values` to make sure that the data is sorted in order, although it appears already so:

```
# sort by `c_id` and `a_date`
df = df.sort_values(['c_id','a_date'])

df['balance'] = df.groupby('c_id')['c_action'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
        a_date  c_id c_name  c_action  balance
0   2016-01-01     1   King      1000     1000
1   2016-01-02     1   King      -200      800
2   2016-01-03     1   King       100      900
3   2016-01-04     1   King      -400      500
4   2016-01-05     1   King       200      700
5   2016-01-06     1   King      -200      500
6   2016-01-01     2  Smith      1000     1000
7   2016-01-02     2  Smith      -300      700
8   2016-01-03     2  Smith      -600      100
9   2016-01-04     2  Smith       100      200
10  2016-01-05     2  Smith      -100      100
```